# Gauss' Theorem - Can't understand a parameterization

Tags: geometry, multivariable-calculus

Given the following file (example 6):
http://math.bard.edu/~mbelk/math601/GaussExamples.pdf

Can someone please explain to me how did he move from the parameterization
$ t=\theta, r=cos(u), z=sin(2u) $ where $ 0\leq t \leq 2\pi , -\frac{\pi}{2}\leq u \leq \frac{\pi}{2} $ to $x=cos(u)cos(t) , y=cos(u)sin(t) , z=sin(2u)$ ?

Can someone help me understand this geometrically ?

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are using cylindrical coordinates. You can look it up on Wikipedia or in almost any book dealing with the mathematics needed for studying physics or engineering. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cylindrical_coordinate_system

If you still have problems after this, tell me and I'll try to write something more explanatory.

EDIT: Ok, so what they are doing first is modelling a certain curve.
So, let's take a look at the definitions $r=\cos(u)$ and $z=sin(2u)$, where $-\frac{\pi}{2}\le u\le\frac{\pi}{2}$. The range of $u$ can be explained by looking at this graph (which is what we get from solving $r=\cos(u)$ for $u$ and then inserting in $z=sin(2u)$):
(http://www.wolframalpha.com/share/clip?f=d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427ec0ushsif44)
We only want the right side of it, which is from $r=0$ to $r=1$, which means u going from $0$ ($r=1$) to $\frac{\pi}{2}$ ($r=0$). Here we always have $z=\sin(2u)\ge 0$ If we now want to add the negative side of the graph in example 6, we simply have to add the intervall$[-\frac{\pi}{2},0]$, so that $z=sin(2u)\le 0$.
Thus $-\frac{\pi}{2}\le u\le\frac{\pi}{2}$.
Ok, so this is how we get the graph and rotating it gives us the wished surface.

!!!MOST IMPORTANT!!!

We just express $r$ and $z$, which are our coordinates, as functions of a parameter $u$, so that when we insert them into the integral, they give us a formula that describes our structure. We can still use them as coordinates. We are basically doing a substitution (like when solving some integrals) in order to express how they depend on each other. That's all there is to parametrization.

Now let's deal with the coordinate system (because there might be some misunderstandings), so that we can actually work with it. For our porblem, we decide to use cylindrical coordinates. You can easily derive cylindrical coordinates from polar coordinates. So, let's start with that:

[image: polar]

So for a vector $\vec v\in R^2$ with coordinates $v=\left(\begin{array}{c} x \\ y \end{array}\right)$, we can define $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ as the vector's length and $\phi$ as the angle between the x-axis and the vector. Then, we draw a circle with radius $r$. Now, we see that $x=r\cdot\cos(\phi)$ and $y=r\cdot\sin(\phi)$. And using this identity is what is done in example 6:

The parametrisation there introduces us to $t=\theta$, where $0\le t\le 2\pi$, so basically just like our angle $\phi$ in polar coordinates. So, $x=r\cdot\cos(\phi)=\cos(u)\cdot\cos(t)$ and $y=r\cdot\sin(\phi)=\cos(u)\cdot\sin(t)$ just by plugging in our definitions.

And now we just add a third axis $z$:

[image: cyl]

Comment: : 
They took the coordinate system $(r,z)$ and rotated the curve about the $z$ axis. I guess they denote the third axis as $t$ . So, we take $z=sin(2u)$ . But how did they move from the data around $r$ back to $x,y$ ? I can't figure this out, and the expressions for $x,y$ don't look like cylindrical coordinates, but like spherical ones... Will you please help me?

Comment: and even when using spherical coordinates, I can't understand how they deduced the limits of $t$ , and can't understand why they took  $x=cosu cost , y=cosu sint $ and not $ x=sinu cost , y=sinu sin t$ like spherical coordinates look like... 
Is there any geometrical explanation ? Thanks!

Comment: Ok. I am writing something.

Comment: Sorry, made a mistake with the boundaries. Correcting it now.

Comment: WOW!!! Thanks a lot !!!! I think I understand everything but I will reread it tomorrow and ask you again if I won't get something . Thanks a lot again !you have been very helpful!

Comment: Glad I could help. The most important part really is that you use the variable $u$ only to express the relationship of the coordinates $r$ and $z$ for your structure.

Comment: Thanks again. But, we have the picture of the rotated figure, when our three coordinates are $(r,\theta, z)$ . How can I know the structure of the rotated body in our $(x,y,z)$ coordinate system?

Comment: Well, the structure remains the same when you use $(x,y,z)$ coordinates of course, only the functions you use to describe it just look a little bit different and probably much more difficult.

Comment: This is true only because we chose to work with cylindrical coordinates or will be true in any coordinate system ?

Comment: Imagine a ball in your room. Now you can define a coordinate system and find a position $(x,y,z)$ for each point of it. If you now choose another coordinate system, does this change the ball's shape?

Comment: Great. Thanks a lot !!!!

Comment: M: I'm sorry, but I have to reask you  about your last statement : 
Let's look at the unit ball in Cartesian coordinates. 
when moving to polar coordinates, we get the figure $0\leq r \leq 1 , 0\leq \theta \ leq 2\pi $ , which is a rectangle and not a ball anymore... How does this agree with your statement that in every coordinate system our figure will look the same ? Hope now you'll be able to help ...

Comment: Hi, sorry for not answering for so long :(. I procrastinated a little. In polar coordinates this is still a disk and not a rectangle since polar coordinate lines don't go "straight". In fact they are curved and therefore you end with a disk instead of a rectangle.